# How do I increment certain values in Tensorflow tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

I want to increment certain values of an tensor in Tensorflow. The code I am attempting to use is:

```
outs[h, i:i+self.cnv, j:j+self.cnv] += (self.b*counts)/sums
```

I am not sure how to do this, and the shapes of the Tensors do match, and I am using tf version 2.9.1. The error message is:

```
TypeError: 'Tensor' object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/75823/142167

Comment: You can use `tf.tensor_scatter_nd_add`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No easy way of doing it. But here is one way:

`An Example:`

```
inputs = tf.random.uniform(maxval=10, dtype=tf.int32, shape=(2, 3, 2))
```

> ```
> array([[[0, 1],
>         [0, 8],
>         [4, 1]],
>
>        [[4, 6],
>         [2, 8],
>         [5, 4]]], dtype=int32)>
> ```

```
#Convert to tf.Variable to make the assignment
temp = tf.Variable(inputs)
h,i,offset,value = 1, 1, 2,100 #try some random offset

temp[h, i:i+offset].assign(temp[h, i:i+offset]+value)
out = tf.convert_to_tensor(temp)
```

> ```
> #output after assignment
> array([[[  0,   1],
>     [  0,   8],
>     [  4,   1]],
>
>    [[  4,   6],
>     [102, 108],
>     [105, 104]]], dtype=int32)>
> ```