# Tensorflow/Keras: Modify weights inside train_step function before gradient computation

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

In the *train_step* function of a Keras Functional Model, we have:

```
def train_step(self, data):
    # Unpack the data. Its structure depends on your model and
    # on what you pass to `fit()`.
    x, y = data

    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)  # Forward pass
        # Compute the loss value
        # (the loss function is configured in `compile()`)
        loss = self.compiled_loss(y, y_pred, regularization_losses=self.losses)

    # Compute gradients
    trainable_vars = self.trainable_variables
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, trainable_vars)
    # Update weights
    self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, trainable_vars))
    # Update metrics (includes the metric that tracks the loss)
    self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, y_pred)
    # Return a dict mapping metric names to current value
    return {m.name: m.result() for m in self.metrics}
```

I want to be able to change the self.weights inside the function. When it calls `y_pred = self(x, training=True)` it will use the original weights, but I want to change these weights before computing the gradient and applying `self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, trainable_vars))`. The idea is to apply the gradient based on the loss with previous weights to the new weights.

1- I first tried with `self.set_weights(x)` after computing the loss and before computing the gradients but this error arises: `RuntimeError: Cannot get value inside Tensorflow graph function.`

2- I saw that this could be resolved with `run_eagerly=True` but then `WARNING:tensorflow:5 out of the last 5 calls to <function pfor.<locals>.f at 0x29d89bf70> triggered tf.function retracing. Tracing is expensive and the excessive number of tracings could be due to (1) creating @tf.function repeatedly in a loop, (2) passing tensors with different shapes, (3) passing Python objects instead of tensors. For (1), please define your @tf.function outside of the loop. For (2), @tf.function has reduce_retracing=True option that can avoid unnecessary retracing. For (3), please refer to https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#controlling_retracing`

3- Moreover, the results with `run_eagerly=True` are quite different, so I am not sure if this solution is working correctly.

Is it possible to change the weights before the gradient computation as I want with Keras?

Extra clarification: let's imagine we have two arrays of weights A and B, and these arrays are correlated. I want to get the LOSS with A weights but then optimize B weights with LOSS. Optimizing B from the LOSS of A makes sense because these weight arrays are correlated.

Comment: you should get your weights from `trainable_variables`. Check- `for var in trainable_variables:
    print(var.name)`

Comment: thx for the answer, however, unless I put run_eagerly=True, I can't modify the variable "EagerTensor' object does not support item assignment". Running it eagerly should give the same results?

Comment: check - https://stackoverflow.com/a/74246916/8143158