# Tensorflow: Generating of a random mask tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

Hi I am trying to generate a mask i.e. which have in a random positioned square a value of 1 and 0 elsewhere

```
import tensorflow as tf
l=8 #size of my mask
mask=tf.zeros(shape=[1,l,l,1])
l_nonzeros=tf.random.uniform(shape=[],minval=0, maxval=l-1, dtype="int32")
x=tf.random.uniform(shape=[],minval=0, maxval=l, dtype="int32")
y=tf.random.uniform(shape=[],minval=0, maxval=l, dtype="int32")
mask[:,-x:(-x+l_nonzeros),-y:(-y+l_nonzeros),:]=1
```

I get an "tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object does not support item assignment". As I understood it correctly, I can't assign a value to a tensor in this way. How I can circumvent that problem?

Thanks for any Help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74246916/8143158

Comment: For what do you need this mask?

Comment: I would like to implement a CutMix approach (i.e. mixing of two images by replacement of a squared region in one image by the corresponding part of the other image)